# Car touch-up paint... HELP!

Tags: paint, detailing

I've tried to fix some chipping paint and a tiny rust spot... and created myself a bigger problem:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/yZCFZb1YmR8JGkZa6

I back-taped everything carefully... and still got these completely obvious lines - no blending at all.
But this turned to be the lesser of my problems. I started 1000 grit wet-sending (*gently* and with a block), and **the paint is coming right off**. I'm only guessing that we're seeing the primer underneath it.

The paint job included 3 layers of primer, 3 basecoat, and 4 clearcoat (all from Automotive Touchup), with ample drying time between layers. The wet sanding I tried today... that was 3 weeks after the clearcoat. And yet it's coming right off, as if I applied no clearcoat and 1 layer of paint 10 minutes ago.

What is going on?? And how can I mitigate this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have sprayed too many layers. When this happens the paint tends to chip or flake right off as your describing. As to the tape lines, using tape will always leave a line and will also mis-layer your paint job. This could also be why your paint is flaking off, as there is uneven layering done.